# Additional push event syncing between Artifactory instances

Tags: artifactory

We have two instances of Artifactory for Prod and Non-Prod.

Normal syncing happens via a pull mechanism by the Prod instance.

Is it possible to also have an additional push event sync from Non Prod instance to the Prod that we would use for hotfixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set up push event-driven replication. Please note that while pull replication prepopulates remote repository in server A from a local repository in server B, push replication replicates between two local repositories. Once you set up a virtual repository it doesn't really matter because you'll have a single point of access anyway, but just something for you to be aware of.

You can read more about push replication and pull replication in [the user guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication). Also, please [find here a whitepaper on different replication topologies](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/replication-using-artifactory-to-manage-binaries-across-multi-site-topologies/) and [a webinar on the same topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HIwODsETMg).